# Running individual integration tests in React Native

Tags: react-native

After opening the react native UIExplorer example, I'm able to quickly run the test suite with cmd+u in XCode. Reading through the code as instructed by the docs, I come to this piece of code in `IntegrationTestsApp.js`:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.row}>
      Click on a test to run it in this shell for easier debugging and
      development.  Run all tests in the testing environment with cmd+U in
      Xcode.
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.separator} />
    <ScrollView>
      {TESTS.map((test) => [
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.setState({test})}
          style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.testName}>
            {test.displayName}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
        <View style={styles.separator} />
      ])}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

How do I run the test app so that I am able to manually run each test ("Click on each test")?

Answer (score 1):

I did find *a solution*, though at the time of writing it seems like *quite* a hack. Essentially, I ran the `IntegrationTestsApp` as the main app via:

1. changing the rootView in `AppDelegate` to:

   ```
   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
   moduleName:@"IntegrationTestsApp" initialProperties:nil];
   ```
2. changing the sourceURL to the file exporting the above module:

   ```
   sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerIntegrationTests/js/IntegrationTestsApp.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
   ```
3. Linking RCTTest.a in "Build Phases"

   Again, I'm hoping for a better answer but this *appears* to work